# How do I configure File schema history storage for Debezium MySql connector?

Tags: debezium-engine

I'm writing a Debezium (2.3.2) Engine program. After running successfully with Postgres, I switched to MySQL but hit the following problem:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value io.debezium.storage.kafka.history.KafkaSchemaHistory for configuration schema.history.internal: Class io.debezium.storage.kafka.history.KafkaSchemaHistory could not be found.
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:744)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef$ConfigKey.<init>(ConfigDef.java:1172)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:152)
        at io.debezium.config.Field.group(Field.java:453)
        at io.debezium.config.ConfigDefinition.addToConfigDef(ConfigDefinition.java:104)
        at io.debezium.config.ConfigDefinition.configDef(ConfigDefinition.java:71)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorConfig.configDef(MySqlConnectorConfig.java:922)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector.config(MySqlConnector.java:76)
        at io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine.run(EmbeddedEngine.java:717)
        at io.debezium.embedded.ConvertingEngineBuilder$2.run(ConvertingEngineBuilder.java:229)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I want to avoid Kafka entirely, so I don't want to use KafkaSchemaHistory

I tried adding the following properties:

```
schema.history.internal=io.debezium.storage.file.history.FileSchemaHistory
schema.history.internal.file.filename=mysql-schema-history.dat
```

But I still get the same error, can anyone give me a clue what the right properties are?